# How can I handle the output in multiple processes without passing parameters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

How do I share a queue to a number of processes,the code of these processes in multiple files, and I don't want to pass the queue as parameter.

I try to solve the problem, but failed.
I have three files

`main.py`

```
from p_1 import test
from p_2 import queue_run
import multiprocessing


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)
    process_2 = queue_run()
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
```

`p_1.py`

```
import time
from p_2 import queue_put


def test():
    var = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    for v in var:
        queue_put('something : ' + v)
        time.sleep(0.8)
```

`p_2.py`

```
import multiprocessing

queue = multiprocessing.Queue()


def queue_put(something):
    queue.put(something)

class queue_run(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = queue.get(timeout=1)
                print data
            except:
                break
```

Then I run main.py, but without any output.

Comment: although you **should** pass the queue as a parameter, it seems to work also having it as global variable. Anyway: I cannot reproduce. When I run `python2 main.py` I get `something : a` from a to d

Comment: That's unbelievable, I had try to run main.py on cmdline and Pycharm, I did not get any output.

Comment: Does it still not work? I have reworked your example into something which is better aligned to the design of multiprocessing. I can post that if you want

Comment: Oh, yes, I still did not solve the problem. If you can, I would like to see your code.

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: yes, I work on Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs about [exchanging data between processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) explain that you hand over the queue to the process as an argument. Your code worked on my Mac (I would call that "by chance" as it's using undocumented feature which might be just a side effect of one python version), but not on Windows.

An important fact is that processes started with `multiprocessing` don't have a shared memory space (unlike threads, which do share their memory). The mechanisms to share objects are [pipes, queues](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) and objects created via [shared memory or server processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

That said: there are a few things which I would improve in your code:

- the split into three modules does not make sense to me, especially `p_1.py` and `p_2.py`
- it's not clear why you did a class `queue_run` when a normal function similar to `test` would do the trick as well

Here's your example, condensed into one file. I left the class so you can see easily what I changed:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def test(queue):
    var = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    for v in var:
        queue_put(queue, 'something : ' + v)
        time.sleep(0.8)


def queue_put(queue, something):
    queue.put(something)

class queue_run(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, q):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.queue = q

    def run(self):
        print "started"
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.queue.get(timeout=1)
                print "got from queue: ", data
            except:
                print "timed out"
                break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    process_1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args=(queue,))
    process_2 = queue_run(queue)
    process_1.start()
    process_2.start()
    process_1.join()
    process_2.join()
```

P.S. you may want to call `test` producer and `queue_run` consumer, that's how they are called in programming jargon

**Update**:

> if I pass the queue as a parameter to all sub modules to solve the above problem, I need to modify all the files, this is a complex project

As you're working on Windows (as you noted in a comment) there's an important fact to know: If you create a new process, it will be [spawned](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#contexts-and-start-methods): a new python interpreter is started, your python modules are loaded new, and thus all global variables (like your queue) are initiated afresh with a new instance. That means there is *no way* to share a global variable with processes.

If you want to stay with multiprocessing, the only way is to pass them to the submodules. I cannot imagine that you have more than 50 submodules, so an hour of work with a good editor should do the trick.

The alternative though is to use [**threading**](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/): the downside is that you can only use one cpu core, the upside is that all your threads share the same memory space. The only thing you need to care about is to use thread safe data structures, such as a [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue).

Comment: Although the code doesn't work well on my Windows(this may be related to the platform), thank you very much.

Comment: On windows, process `queue_run` seems running in a separate memory space, `queue.get(timeout=1)` timeout but didn't get anything and raise `Empty` then quit. So I didn't get anything output. On linux, I got the same result as you.`something : a`..

Comment: Alright. I'll try to debug on Windows in a few hours

Comment: @H.Wozniak, oh, I mistakenly posted the wrong python code which didn't hand over queue to the processes. I corrected the answer. This one works now, I've tested with Windows and Python 2.7

Comment: bottom line: why your code in the question works on OSX is still puzzling me, as on OSX it's using `fork` which does a separation of memory spaces ("copy on write"). Anyway, with handing over the queues it's guaranteed to work, as that's what the documentation says

Comment: Yes, this is really an interesting question, but it seems I still need to pass the parameters of the method to solve this problem.

Comment: @H.Wozniak does this solve your problem? or why don't you want to have queue as parameter?

Comment: I have a lot of written sub module files, will be in the process of multi-way in different files and different places to start. I would like to use a shared queue to get the output of each module, and then use an independent process to make the output more tidy. However, if I pass the queue as a parameter to all sub modules to solve the above problem, I need to modify all the files, this is a complex project.

Comment: @H.Wozniak: I've added an additional paragraph to my answer which handles this question

Comment: `All resources of the parent are inherited by the child process.` `The default on Unix.` So we can explain why the code can worked well on OSX !

Comment: @H.Wozniak exactly

Comment: This is really an interesting language. I have finished my object, pass the queue to all submodules. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: yes, python is great. multiprocesses is a bit tricky but the nice thing is that you learn a lot about how processes work on Unix or Windows

Comment: Yes, there are many methods I have not tried, and also do not understand the underlying knowledge. I still need to learn.